# Issue found: Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app

Tags: permissions

Facing an issue while uploading my Android application to the Google Play Store, and I'm struggling to resolve it. If anyone has insights or solutions, please share!

I have given this permission to my app.

App Content (google play store)
ore functionalities *
What functionalities in your app require SMS and Call Log permissions?
I selected multiple chose option but not issue fix